# Garbage collector collect memory is application specific or thread specific

Tags: .net, garbage-collection

In operating system when any process creates thread, it will get its own dedicated stack and heap memory. So process and its child thread has their own stack and heap.

Garbage collector is designed to manage heap memory. Now in my .net application, I can create n number of threads, so I will have n number of heaps.

My question is, whether garbage collector runs when any thread(n number of created thread) heap memory is full, or whole application memory is full.

If garbage collector triggers when any thread heap memory is full, more than 1 thread memory can be full at given time, so whether garbage collector will run for both thread simultaneously.

Comment: "get its own dedicated stack" - yes - " and heap " - no. there's one (managed) heap for the process.

Comment: The answer will depend on the version and edition of the framework and it would be very long. SO is a site for concrete problems, not for tutorials.

Comment: This only applies to the server GC.  It is documented to collect on all threads at the same time, so one thread having a full generation should trigger a collection on other ones as well.  Server GC is a pretty mysterious ball of wax.

Comment: Thanks I got it, all thread within process gets allocated on same heap.